# getwindow() in android does not clear previous image

Tags: android, listview

I am using `requestWindowFeature` to show custom dialogue with clickable list view. I want to change dialogue image according to item selection so I make an array.

Everything working correctly but when I clicked on second item from `ListView`, a pop up show me the previous image too please help:

**HERE IS THE JAVA CODE:**

```
int[] images=new int[5];                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
String[] mondaylist={"Incline Betch Press","Flat Dumbbell","Cable Flies","Incline Cable Flies","Seated Pec Fly"};                       
String[] tue_list={"Lat Pull Downs","Lat Close grip","Seated Rows","T-Bar Rows","Cable pull Downs"};                                    
String[] wed_list={"Leg extension","Lying Legs curls","Seated Leg curls","Calf raise","iui"};                                           
String[] thu_list={"Military Press","Seated Dumbbell press","Front Dumbbell Press","Dumbbell Fly","Dumbbell Shrungs"};                  
String[] fri_list={"Dumbbell Curls","Preacher Curls","Cable Biceps Curls","Rope Push downs","Behind the Neck","Triceps Extension"};  

@Override                                                                                                                               
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                                    
    final Dialog builder = new Dialog(this);                                                                                            
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_SWIPE_TO_DISMISS);                                                                      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                                                                 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_worklist);                                                                                                                                                                     
    ListView l1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);                                                                                 
    CustomAdapter ca=new CustomAdapter();                                                                                                                                                                                              
    l1.setAdapter(ca);                                                                                                                  
    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {                                                                   

        @Override                                                                                                                       
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {                                                 
            builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(                                                                                  
                    new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));                                                             
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {                                                      
                @Override                                                                                                               
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {                                                                

                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            });                                                                                                                         

            ImageView image = new ImageView(worklist.this);                                                                                                                                                           
            image.setImageResource(images[i]);                                                                                                                                                                     
            builder.addContentView(image, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(                                                                
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                                                                                
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT                                                                                 

            ));                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            builder.show();                                                                                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                               
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is that you are trying to re-use existing dialog. If you read the documentation of `Dialog#addContentView` you'll find the following:

> Add an additional content view to the screen.  Added after any
>   existing ones in the screen -- existing views are NOT removed.

So you add image on top of another image and show them both on the 2nd call. Instead you should create `Dialog` instance inside `onItemClick` click method.

```
    @Override                                                                                                                       
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
        Dialog builder = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);                                                                                            
        builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_SWIPE_TO_DISMISS);                                                 
        builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(                                                                                  
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));                                                             
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {                                                      
            @Override                                                                                                               
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {                                                                

            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        });
        ...
```